# Licensing constraints to Business Intelligence projects for Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, licensing

Since the business intelligence development studio only seems to come with SQL server discs and you have to install from those discs in order to see the projects inside Visual Studio, are there licensing constraints that I should be aware of?  Like only one installation of the business intelligence studio per server?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1):

Although I must preface my response with the worn expression "I'm no licensing expert", I will take a stab at this.  I believe your BIDS installation limitations are imposed by SQL Server licensing.  If your developer has a MSDN subscription (any team edition) then they are licensed to install BIDS on any number of desktops that they use.  If you have a SQL Server license on a server, then you can install BIDS on the server that you are using for the SQL Server license.  If you want a free copy of SSRS for development purposes and don't have a MSDN subscription, then you can install [SQL Server Express with Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B5D1B8C3-FDA5-4508-B0D0-1311D670E336&displaylang=en).  If you have a production SQL Server license then you probably are licensed for some development SQL Servers.  My guess is you may be able to do development work on one of these servers directly without a MSDN Subscription, but I don't really know for sure.  Hope this helps in some way.